# Using CSS3 Animations to move in different directions at certain 50%

Tags: html, css

i have a simple CSS animation at the moment where the animation moves the image from top left to bottom right of my banner canvas (300x250) but 50% through i need to start to move towards bottom left and then 100% finish off with moving it back towards the bottom right but as new to css animations not sure how to do this. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Done a little diagram here:

[image]

And example:

```css
.train-container {
 position: relative;
}

.train {
 position: absolute;
 top: -350px;
 left: -250px;
}

@keyframes moveTrain {
 0% {
  transform: translate(-185px,-159px);
 }
   100% {
    transform: translate(300px,250px);
   }
}

.train-container {
 animation-duration: 30s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 animation-name: moveTrain;
 position: absolute; 
}

.train-container {
 .train {
  transform: scale(0.65);
 }
}
```

Comment: you do realise that the path you drew has 4 Points and the animation you described only has 3 right? maybe you mean 100% - 66.66% - 33.33% - 0

Comment: i dont exactly understand what is the question here move the banner with zigzag and move back or stay wherever it is ?

Comment: Yea more or less in a zigg zagg motion, hard to explain lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your animation is working so far, all you need to do is to add more keyframes.

Right now you have the keyframes for 0% and 100%. Add 2 more frames with 33% and 66% in between and set their location.

```
@keyframes moveTrain {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-185px,-159px);
    }
    33% {
        transform: translate(VALUE, VALUE);
    }
    66% {
        transform: translate(VALUE, VALUE);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(300px,250px);
    }
}
```

Just specify the wanted location values in the added keyframes.

You can also use other values for the keyframes than 33% and 66%, and you can also add even more

Comment: Do you know how i work out the locations of what i need? i tried 0,0 and 150px,125px sorry for being dumb with this.

Comment: You can just guess the locations. Also, i would recommend to start at position 0, 0 or end at position 0, 0. The first value in the brackets is the X position, the second the Y position. A higher X-pos moves the image to the right, a higher Y-pos moves it down. You could tryit this way: 1. (0px, 0px); 2. (150px, 50px); 3. (0px, 100px); 4. (150px, 150px); This should be more or less what you are trying to achieve. maxbe with a bit of modification